# How do I hide certain pages in jQuery mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm building my first jQuery mobile app but am not certain how to set up the different pages. Right now I just want the div labeled with id "one" to show, then I want a link that when pressed shows the div labeled id "two". I'm creating a reading application with different phases and I only want one phase to show at a time. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="one">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Phase 1</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4><a href="#two">Next</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    <div data-role="page" id="two">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Phase 2</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these or check these codes in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UbGp/60/).

```
<div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Phase One</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>Page content goes here.</p>
            </div>
                <li><a href="#page2">Next</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1>Phase Two</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->  
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id='aDiv'>Page content goes here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```